# Can I run the AppFabric ACS in a private cloud?

Tags: appfabric, adfs, acs

Can i install the appfabric on my private servers and get the same services that ACS provides in the cloud? specifically I want to be able to accept Live Id, Goggle and Facebook logins in my asp.net mvc application but I don't want to use Azure or pay for another cloud based product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without ACS. The Facebook etc. integration is simply an OAuth / OpenID interface on the other side of ACS.

As an example see [Sign into SharePoint 2010 with Facebook using a custom STS](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/nielsen_travis/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=40).

You'll see it refers to a custom C# class which is used to do the actual work of the oAuth 2.0 authentication. You can do a similar thing from your ASP app.

Also have a look at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/). This supports OpenID 2.0 and 1.x and OAuth 1.0 and 1.0a.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the STS we have to use is ADSF 2.0 and i was hoping to not have to do the work of integrating, then maintaining the integration, each of the different providers (live id, facebook, google, etc)

Comment: Sadly, you can't customise ADFS to this level. Have a look at http://startersts.codeplex.com/. This is a good example of an STS which has the DotNetOpenAuth component added (and also look at http://identityserver.codeplex.com/ - its successor).

Comment: Azure ACS is only available as a cloud service.  @nzpcmad's answer will do the trick, but I doubt you get a cheaper implementation than Microsoft's setup. ACS is free for this year. (2011)